# Communication between rest services hosted on different tomcat servers

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat, jax-rs

I have a scenario where i am hosting different java Rest Services on different Tomcat instances (different machines). These projects running on the tomcats do not have any UI. For simplicity's sake, lets assume that the user will directly enter some URL in the browser (or curl) to avail these services. Now I need this service to be able to talk to (call functions) the services available in the other tomcat instance.
For eg. If TomcatInstance1 gets the call, and all this does is act as a 'router' to the different services, i want it to be able to place the Rest call for the other 'service' available on, say, TomcatInstance2. Is this possible?. If so, how to achieve that? (Tried searching for similar questions on SO, couldnt find any). Are there any online reference for the same?

PS: Hosting the services in the same Tomcat Instance is against the requirement that I'm having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is completely possible. You can use (for example) Jersey-client (http://jersey.java.net/) to make the queries to the other RESTful web services in the other Tomcat instances. Only need to define the correct URIs of the end points and query them according the the API exposed and call it (like you were a client from a browser, or curl).

See here a nice example of using Jersey-client to do that: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/

Comment: How do i manage the dependencies. I use ANT and not Maven, hence pom.xml is out of question. Is there any dependency management solution in ANT?

Comment: Not completely sure, but I do think for the client you will need: https://jersey.java.net/project-info/2.0/jersey/jersey-client/dependencies.html however you should probably think of using maven or at least explore a more "automated" way to do this, it does seem to be possible to include "maven dependencies" in ant (I have no experience with that), look here: http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Spring Restful api ( http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html , http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/ ).

As @emgsilva mentioned the only thing you need to do is to point correct uris between each other.

The beauty of spring restful api is it is simple to use and you don't deal with any serialization - deserialization.